# How can I force TAB in org-mode to properly align plain lists?

Tags: emacs, tabs, org-mode

When using org-mode, I frequently write plain lists using either '-' or numbers. When I move to the next line using RET then TAB, the cursor always moves eight spaces beyond the start of the line instead of aligned with the list "marker" above.

This screenshot should be helpful to see what I mean...

[alt text http://www2.ryankaskel.com/misc/images/screenshots/emacs-org-mode-tabs_20100603.png](http://www2.ryankaskel.com/misc/images/screenshots/emacs-org-mode-tabs_20100603.png)

Thanks for your help,
Ryan Kaskel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-return</kbd> (i.e., `org-meta-return`); I think it does what you want, and more.

Comment: Great, thanks! I missed that in the docs but here is the reference for anyone else who finds this http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#Plain-lists.

Answer (score 3):

You should also check out org-indent-mode.

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at customizing the `org-blank-before-new-entry` variable to prevent the insertion of blank lines between items when using <kbd>M-return</kbd>.